# Relational databases guaranties when transfering money between accounts

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

Let's image we have a database table:

```
account
id | balance
```

There is only one operation of moving money from one account to another. Like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE account SET balance = balance - 100 WHERE account_id = 1;
UPDATE account SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE account_id = 2;
COMMIT;
```

From application, we can initiate transfer from `Account1` to `Account2` and from `Account2` to `Account1` in parallel.

I'm trying to understand `Isolation level` guarantees. As I see there is no case when `Non-Repeatable` problem can occur as there is not two reads from same row inside one transaction. So I just should care of `Dirty Read` scenario and `Read Commited` *Isolation level* gives me **enough** guarantees that my Application is going to work correctly?

I don't even need to have any pessimistic lock to support only this case, am I thinking right?
if it is not, could you give me an example when my guarantees are violated?

Comment: Do you mean `COMMIT` instead of `ROLLBACK`?

Comment: Your scenario isn't realistic -- in a real system there would be more than two accounts, and they would be parameterized, so that account 3 could also be trying to withdraw from account 1, for example. There would also likely be a check that a balance can't go below 0. So yes, you definitely need locks here. (Actually, in a *real* system this sort of stuff generally doesn't happen at all because financial systems typically use transaction ledgers with the state derived from those rather than directly mutating rows, but that's another matter.)

Comment: Yeah, I meant COMMIT. But in this far-fetched scenario, all will be good and transactions just will be roll-backed in case of violations?

Comment: You don't need to worry about dirty reads - they are never possible in Postgres

Comment: "my Application is going to work correctly"  What would that mean?  That there is no deadlock risk?  That money can't materialize or simply vanish?  That no one can overdraw their account (you don't even seem to be attempting to prevent that)?

Comment: @jjanes it should be protected from all mentioned things by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level guarantees that no concurrent transaction can see dirty data, and no anomaly can happen, because the `UPDATE`s read and write in the same transaction.

What *could* happen is a deadlock if a second money transfer from account 2 to account 1 happens at exactly the same time. But that is also no problem for data integrity. You can avoid such deadlocks if all transactions update the account with the lower number first, no matter in which direction the transfer is done.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my question, I was asked it at interview.

Comment: If deadlock occurred, common behavior is - one transaction will be roll-backed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the deadlock detector kicks in and cancels one of the locked statements.

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario you can lock the table untill the transation is finished

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM account  WHERE  account_id IN(1,2) FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE account SET balance = balance - 100 WHERE account_id = 1;
UPDATE account SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE account_id = 2;
COMMIT;
END ;
```

Also is possible to lock a entire table and even specify a condition:

LOCK TABLE account IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

Comment: That doesn't really address the question, and `LOCK TABLE` is evil.

Comment: According to the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS), select for update will only lock the rows provided in the where clause.
It's also important to lock both the origin and destination account rows to avoid a potential deadlock scenario.